# JQMIGRATE: Logging is active - how to disable

Tags: joomla-3.x, jquery

I'm using Joomla 3.4 stable and I seem to be getting Javascript console messages:

```
JQMIGRATE: Logging is active
JQMIGRATE: jQuery.browser is deprecated
```

Debug mode in Joomla is turned off so I don't know why these are displaying and I haven't modified any core code. Any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the exact same thing a couple of days ago when testing some avatars in our extension.

The message you've provided is being produced by Community Builder as it's importing jQuery Migrate (uncompressed).

You can either, download the minified version and replace it, or open the current file and replace:

```
jQuery.migrateMute = false
```

with

```
jQuery.migrateMute = true
```

Comment: Thanks for that. I'm not actually using Community Builder so mush have been another extension that has caused the problem. Either way resolved with your solution. Thanks

Comment: Joomla core uses jQuery migrate by default see the code at https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/blob/staging/libraries/cms/html/jquery.php#L25-L70

Comment: @GeorgeWilson - Joomla imports minified files by default. jQuery migrate does not throw this error in the minified version, so unless the OP has debug mode enabled, it's not a core Joomla related issue